# Appropriate sentence

Tags: sentence-request

There is a task. Put  words in the sentences into correct order.

**For /a day/ of/for/ task/ and/ time/ spend/ more/ for/ it/ example/  limit / don't/ some/ set/ one/ hour/ a**

*My sentence: For example set a limit of one hour a day for this task and don’t spend more time for it*

***good/ at/  time/ to find/ information/ about/ the / all/ down/ I/ am / didn't/ but/ I*** **/the/ things/ I/ have/ much/ organization/ wrote/ out**

**are/ and/ both/ develop/ grammar/ important/ vocablary/ skills/ to**

(It is - the missing word) to develop both grammar and vocabulary skills.

But in this the sentence is incorrect.

I think in every of these sentences there are some words missed. In the last sentence as I understand there are to things to be compared. But there aren't. T. e. it is impossible to make the correct sentences.

Can you help understand what exactly is wrong about these sentences?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! How far have you go with this? There's a lot of us willing to help with things, but we not generally about doing whole tasks for people. If you think there's words missing, what do you think the sentences should be, and what words do you think are missing?

Comment: There is no "this" in the words collection of the first sentence, but "some".

Comment: sentence 3 can be "Both grammar and vocabulary are important skills to develop."

Answer (score 2):

They seem like puzzles more than exercises to learn English, so I think you are right in your objection.

---

As for the first one:

> [You already solved it]

- For this kind of exercises, try to collect the phrases that catch your eyes first, then reorder and mix them into a complete sentence. Here, "one hour a day" is an idiomatic expression, so it can be lifted off first.

---

The second sentence:

> I wrote down all the things I am good at, but I didn't have much information to find out about the time organization.

---

The last one:

> Both grammar and vocabulary are important skills to develop.

- You can see that there is no comparison here as the word "both" was used, not "than" for example.

---

Lastly, don't ever doubt the question since it is very rare for books to contain mistakes, and it would just make the homework harder on you to do.

Comment: Please, edited version.

Comment: I can't edit my text, as lost my profile. So my variants.

Comment: For example set a limit of one hour a day for this task and don’t spend more time for it.                 Grammar and vocablary skills are both important ti develop.

Comment: The first one seems more reasonable than mine. The second one can have "both" in the middle and beginning of the sentence. I have actually written it in the middle first but found that at the beginning seem smoother. Thank you for offering them.

Comment: I did the second one. And sorry about the misunderstanding earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence you created is grammatically and semantically correct. If it was not accepted, perhaps the intended sentence was instead:

**Set a limit of, for example, one hour a day for this task and don’t spend more time for it**.

For the second I think the intended sentence is

**I didn't have much time to find out all the information about the organization but I wrote down all the things I am good at**.

For the third sentence you can use the given words to create

**Grammar and vocabulary are both important skills to develop**.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept your answer. I lost the profile I wrote from. But I voted for your answer. Thank you very much!